# SOAP request in Python not able to pull data from public database (XML form)

Tags: python, xml, soap

I'm trying to pull vessel data from the US Coast Guard publicly available database. They provide the return variables and also the SOAP code to access the data.

[This is the link](https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx?op=getVesselDeficienciesXMLString).

I did my best to copy/paste this code into Python with a few edits as I've seen from other examples.

The Activity ID # I have entered is a valid one.

```
import requests

from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

import pandas as pd

 
url=https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx

headers= {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml',

           'SOAPAction': 'http://cgmix.uscg.mil/getVesselDeficiencies'}
 

body= """<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance xmlns:xsd=http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema xmlns:soap12=http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope>

  <soap12:Body>

    <getVesselDeficienciesXMLString xmlns=http://cgmix.uscg.mil>

      <ActivityNumber>6692725</ActivityNumber>

    </getVesselDeficienciesXMLString>

  </soap12:Body>

</soap12:Envelope>"""


response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)

print (response.content)
```

This didn't return an error, but nor did it provide anything helpful to what I'm looking for.

Also, on the link above that provided the SOAP code, it's clear that the Returns include more than the Activity Number; I would like to access the other fields like System, Description, FailureCauseLookupName, IsReolved, etc. How can I do that?

Comment: For one thing, you did not send a content-type of text/xml.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests

#from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

#import pandas as pd


url='https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx'

headers= {'content-type': 'application/soap+xml',

           'SOAPAction': 'http://cgmix.uscg.mil/getVesselDeficiencies'}


body= """<soap12:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
<soap12:Body>

    <getVesselDeficienciesXMLString xmlns="http://cgmix.uscg.mil">

      <ActivityNumber>6692725</ActivityNumber>

    </getVesselDeficienciesXMLString>

  </soap12:Body>

</soap12:Envelope>"""


response = requests.post(url,data=body,headers=headers)

print (response.content)
```

The body is wrong it has missing quotes("")

This code gives the XML output,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><soap:Body><getVesselDeficienciesXMLStringResponse xmlns="http://cgmix.uscg.mil"><getVesselDeficienciesXMLStringResult>&lt;NewDataSet /&gt;</getVesselDeficienciesXMLStringResult></getVesselDeficienciesXMLStringResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Please comment if this not works

Comment: Thanks! I made the changes but am still struggling to get all the return fields listed to output correctly.

Answer (score 0):

You were missing the doouble quotes around the namespaces:

```py
url = "https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx"
headers = {
    "content-type": "application/soap+xml",
    "SOAPAction": "http://cgmix.uscg.mil/getVesselDeficiencies",
}

body = """
<soap12:Envelope 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  xmlns:soap12="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
  <soap12:Body>
    <getVesselDeficienciesXMLString xmlns="http://cgmix.uscg.mil">
      <ActivityNumber>6692725</ActivityNumber>
    </getVesselDeficienciesXMLString>
  </soap12:Body>
</soap12:Envelope>
"""

response = requests.post(url, data=body, headers=headers)
print(response.text)
```

Working with SOAP is really a pain in the neck though. It's an old API technology. I use [zeep](https://docs.python-zeep.org/en/master/client.html#creating-the-raw-xml-documents) when I have to deal with the evil:

```py
import zeep

client = zeep.Client("https://cgmix.uscg.mil/xml/PSIXData.asmx?WSDL")
client.service.getVesselDeficienciesXMLString(ActivityNumber=6692725)
```

Comment: Thank you! I made the updates, as well as tried the zeep command, but still struggle to access all the return fields listed in the link.